# Django Foreign Key lookup into Template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Good afternoon,

I have a ticket, notes for the ticket, & the user who constructed the note.  When loading the ticket detail, I want to output the username of the person who wrote it.  I send all the notes for a given ticket to the template, but this contains the foreign key (ID) for the user. (i.e. 1, 2, 3) and not the username (i.e. jdoe, syzerman, jsmith).

How can I convert the ID to the username when I passing back all notes?

**Views function**

```
rpt = Sir.objects.get(pk=sir_id)
status = Sir_Status.objects.get(pk=rpt.status_id)
rpt_notes = Notes.objects.filter(sir_id=sir_id).order_by('-note_date')
form = NotesForm(initial={'status' : status.status})
return render(request, 'details.html', {'rpt' : rpt, 'notes' : rpt_notes, 'form' : form})
```

**Template**

```
 {% for note in notes %}
    On {{ note.note_date }}, {{ note.user_set.username }} noted: {{ note.note }} 
    <hr />
 {% endfor %}
```

If I did a {{ note.note_owner }} it would just output the number 1,2,3...

Thanks for your help as I get my mind around Django.

Comment: what's the code for your note model? If note has a foreignkey to user called `owner` then `{{ note.owner.name }}` would give you what you want. To optimize your queries, you probably want to fetch the owner's name immediately when fetching the notes, so use `select_related`: `rpt_notes=Notes.objects.filter(etc...).select_related('owner')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ note.note_owner }}
```

This will give you access to the user who constructed the note. This is presuming that your Note model has a note_owner field which is a ForeignKey to the user model. If so, you can access the username by doing:

```
{{ note.note_owner.username }}
```